# difference between two successive rows in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

diff between two successive rows(Not date time datatypes).

```
select cast (max(  tb1  a  ) as integer), 
cast (min(  tb1  a  )  as integer)
 from   tb1   where   tb2  c    in (select   Id   from   tb2   where   tb3  c1    =566)
group by   tb2  c    
order by   tb2  c   desc 
limit 2 
offset 0
```

can u please correct it.

Here can I use Windows function??

Comment: Please edit your question. It's hard to read and to be honest it's hard to tell what you exacly asking for too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find the difference between succeessive rows, use the `lead` or `lag` window functions. The documentation contains examples, and there are numerous examples on Stack Overflow already.

Typically it looks something like:

```
select id, the_col - lag(the_col) OVER (ORDER BY id)
from my_table;
```